# using RegExp to validate local and international numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i'm trying to use RegExp to validate phone numbers at the moment i'm using just number check

```
var RE_NUMBERS = new RegExp("^[0-9+]+$");



 if ($("#mobile").val().length > 0 && !RE_NUMBERS.test($("#mobile").val())) {
  markAsError("#mobile");
  errors += "mobile can only contain numbers\n";}
```

That works but it's not the ideal, as some users are not adding the correct format.

What i need to validade is:

if number starts with 04 it's ok (Australian mobile number)

if it doesn't start with 04 than it should have the international format and start with a "+"

so basically if the number is not:

04xx xxx xxx
or 
+XX xxx xxx xxxx

Comment: Something like `/^(04|\+)\d+/`

Comment: ^(04\d{8})|(\+\d{12})$ you may have a try.

Comment: @Chris - seems like a good answer to me, why not post it ?

Comment: Because I don't have a test. Now I post it.

Comment: to make it consistent, you should remove all whitespace before validating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RegExp("^(\\+|04)[0-9]+$");
```

that's the correct use for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(04\d{8})|(\+\d{12})$
```

you may have a try.

Comment: will that check for number only or just number of characters? 
what if i don't want to limit the characters for international number to 12?

Comment: checking for head("04"or"+"), number and number of characters, if you don't want to limit the number of characters, just use "\d+" instead of "\d{12}"

Comment: this code doesn't seem to work are you sure you mean ( instead of [

Comment: var RE_NUMBERS = new RegExp("^(04\d{8})|(\+\d{12})$");

Comment: Could you give me some test string that make my regexp dosen't work?